# References any tables to one object by id parameter and table name in the same way nhibernate ReferencesAny

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, entity-framework-6, nhibernate-mapping

In the fluent nhibernate is possible mapping two or more tables to one single object using one abstract class and the ReferencesAny,  for example:

```
public abstract class UserBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class ClientExample : UserBase
{
    //
}

public class InternalUser : UserBase
{
    //
}

public class ExternalUser : UserBase
{
    //
}


 ReferencesAny(m => m.UserExample) //<----- THIS CLASS IS TYPE abstract class UserBase
                .EntityIdentifierColumn("IdUserExample")
                .EntityTypeColumn("using_table").MetaType<int>()
                .AddMetaValue<ClientExample>(((int)Enums.ClientTable).ToString())
                .AddMetaValue<InternalUser>(((int)Enums.InternalUser).ToString())
                .AddMetaValue<ExternalUser>(((int)Enums.ExternalUser).ToString())           
                .IdentityType<int>()
                .Access.Property()
                .Not.Insert()
```

That works fine using fluent nhibernate, how about using Entity Framework 6?
Is it possible to implement in the same way, but using Entity Framework 6?

Comment: The way you have written your question, you require 'would be answerers' to master both NH and EF, thus reducing the likeliness you get some answers. Maybe should you change your question for asking how to achieve in EF this functionality by explaining the functionality you need, rather than referring to its NHibernate implementation. At most add a small mention linking to NHibernate counterpart if you fear EF users would believe this functionality to be something exotic not implemented anywhere.

Comment: looks like not supported and won't be in the near future https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7623 . You have to manually implement it with 2 properties and code to load it manually. I used this feature a lot and am missing it in my current project which uses EF.